# PHP replace value by key in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[id] => 31299
[name] => 37322426212
[ips] => 
[tech_prefix] => 
[password] => 
[id_voip_hosts] => 
[proxy_mode] => 
[auth_type] => ani
[ani] => 37322426212
[accname] => 
[protocol] => 
[port] => 
[orig_enabled] => 1
[term_enabled] => 
[orig_capacity] => 
[term_capacity] => 
[orig_rate_table] => 7
[term_rate_table] => 
[id_dr_plans] => 
[orig_groups] => 
[term_groups] => 
[notes] => 
)
[1] => Array
(
[id] => 4373
[name] => 37322983029
[ips] => 
[tech_prefix] => 
[password] => 
[id_voip_hosts] => 
[proxy_mode] => 
[auth_type] => ani
[ani] => 37322983029
[accname] => 
[protocol] => 
[port] => 
[orig_enabled] => 1
[term_enabled] => 
[orig_capacity] => 
[term_capacity] => 
[orig_rate_table] => 7
[term_rate_table] => 
[id_dr_plans] => 
[orig_groups] => 
[term_groups] => 
[notes] => 
)
[2] => Array
(
[auth_type] => ani
[name] => 37322983029
[ani] => 37322983029
[orig_enabled] => Array
(
[0] => on
)
[orig_rate_table] => 7
)
)
```

Items with 0,1,2 may be more(3,4...10...and so on).
What I am trying to do is to find array with key `ani` and `name = 37322983029` and replace
`name` with '###' and `ani` to empty:

```
[mane]=>"###",//where name = '37322983029'
[ani]=> //where ani = '37322983029'
```

I tried with `str_replace` but no success.
How can this be done?

Comment: Show the code that you've tried... and BTW: it's _any_, and _no success_

Comment: try like this : `foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $out[$value] = $value;
}`

Comment: use array_replace() function

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, ani is an automatic number identification i guess

Comment: Did you mean `name` where you wrote `[mane]=>"###"`?

Comment: @Егор Грижук I think, you mean [name], not [mane]. This makes your question really confusing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is what you are looking for:

```
foreach($yourArray as &$a)
{
  if($a["ani"] == 37322983029 and $a["ani"] == $a["name"])
  {
    $a["name"] = "###";
    $a["ani"] = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: You and I came up with virtually identical solutions (using `&` to reference the original as `foreach` loops through the array of arrays); I don't think you need the double condition though (even though it seems that `ani` and `name` have the same value for the example given).

Comment: @Floris I've read OP's question at least 5 times and I'm still a bit confused. I think, he wants this double condition. But if not, I hope, my post will at least show him the direction to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you were using `str_replace`, but the following should work (assuming that `ani` and `mane` (or `name`?) are actually string indices into your array - not obvious from your example):

```
foreach($myArray as &$val) {
  if($val['ani'] == 37322983029) {
    $val['ani'] = '';
    $val['name'] = "###";
  }
}
```

**important** Note the use of `&` to pass the value by reference so you are working with actual elements of the array, not copies... In that way, when you modify `$val` you are actually modifying the original array. Without the ampersand, your initial array would be unchanged by the loop.

Also note - it is not clear from your example whether you want to test for just `ani==37322983029` or also for `name=37322983029`. I am sure you can modify the code above to have both conditions (or see Alexxus's answer)

A complete code example (tested, working):

```
<?php
$a = Array(Array('a'=>4, 'b'=>5),Array('a'=>6, 'b'=>7));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($a);
foreach($a as &$v){
    if($v['a']==6) {
      $v['a'] = 12;
      $v['b'] = '';
    }
}
print_r($a);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Produces output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 4
            [b] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 6
            [b] => 7
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 4
            [b] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 12
            [b] => 
        )

)
```